# How to calculate expected value?

Tags: probability, expectation

Expected numbers of 'yes' for following data

A = [1,2,3,5]
B = [5,6,7,8]

A 'yes' is when a^b > b^a where a is value randomly chosen from A and b is value randomly chosen from B . Also numbers a and b are discarded from A and B after randomly chosen.

Please explain how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  There are only $16$ possibilities, so you can go through them.  All with $1$ from $A$ will be no, all with $2$ or $3$ will be yes, and $5$ will be yes unless it is paired with $5$.  Presumably you are picking four disjoint pairs and looking for the count of the pairs which produce yes.

Comment: I have already count the number of yes but how to calculate expected number of yes since i am new to this topic i have very little knowledge on expectation. Thanks!

Comment: The expectation is the average number of yes.  Do you see that there will always be 2 or 3?  What fraction of the time will there be 3?